# reading pdf within the android app

Tags: java, android

I am making an application which require to open pdf within the android app without using any third party application.also i don't want to view my pdf in webview .For this i use PdfViewer.jar  and made a code like below.

java :

```
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

        public class First extends ListActivity {

            String[] pdflist;
            File[] imagelist;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                //setContentView(R.layout.main);

                File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
                    }
                });
                pdflist = new String[imagelist.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < imagelist.length; i++) {
                    pdflist[i] = imagelist[i].getName();
                }
                this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pdflist));
            }

            protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                String path = imagelist[(int) id].getAbsolutePath();
                openPdfIntent(path);
            }

            private void openPdfIntent(String path) {
                try {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
                    intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, path);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}

Second.java



public class Second extends PdfViewerActivity 
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public int getPreviousPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.left_arrow;
}

public int getNextPageImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.right_arrow;
}

public int getZoomInImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_in;
}

public int getZoomOutImageResource() {
    return R.drawable.zoom_out;
}

public int getPdfPasswordLayoutResource() {
    return R.layout.pdf_file_password;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberResource() {
    return R.layout.dialog_pagenumber;
}

public int getPdfPasswordEditField() {
    return R.id.etPassword;
}

public int getPdfPasswordOkButton() {
    return R.id.btOK;
}

public int getPdfPasswordExitButton() {
    return R.id.btExit;
}

public int getPdfPageNumberEditField() {
    return R.id.pagenum_edit;
}
}
```

i have added my second.java in android menifest too.But my logcat is showing the following error.M not getting the error

logcat :

```
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d8b368 that was originally bound here
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-12 09:23:50.408: E/ActivityThread(713):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-12 09:23:50.455: E/StrictMode(713): null
```

Any hepl??

Comment: Write your own PDF redering library if you don't want to use a third party one.

Comment: i want to use PdfViewer.jar for achieving this.I am newbie to android i dont have any knowledge about how can i use that .

Comment: @sonia, Read the documentation for PdfViewer.jar, then try to use it. Your question is too broad to be answered properly, so please try to solve it yourself first, and then come back with any specific issues you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper library in your application handling the pdf logic. When using a library inside your own application no other application is started to view/modify the pdf.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android for a summary of available pdf libraries.

Answer (score -2):

```
Use following code. But PDF viewer application must present on device.

 File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/video/"+filePath); 
            if(pdfFile.exists()) 
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try
                {
                    startActivity(pdfIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
```

Comment: The OP specifically said he doesn't want to use a third party application.

Comment: filepath is pdf fileName or path. in my sample /sdcard/video/'filepath' is just sample.

Comment: i dont want my app to read any pdf from raw folder.i want it to read pdf that it got from web server.